# Browser geolocation API verification order

Tags: javascript, html, browser, geolocation

What is the order of methods used to detect the location of a visitor that Geolocation Browser API uses?

On the W3C Geolocation info site it says that it uses a combination of IP, Wi-Fi, Cell-Phone and GPS, but it doesnt say the order that it uses to do this.

From my understanding, it uses GPS (if available) and then one of the other 3 methods, but it is not clear which comes next.

I need this in a project where I have to determine the user location without using his IP.

Answer (score 1):

The API doesn't get a user's location; it requests it from the browser (which, I believe, gets it from the OS - but correct me if I'm wrong). The exact method depends on the hardware available, and the raw data is not accessible through the API. From [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/obtain-location?hl=en) Google Developers page:

> The API is device-agnostic; it doesn't care how the browser determines
>   location, so long as clients can request and receive location data in
>   a standard way. The underlying mechanism might be via GPS, wifi, or
>   simply asking the user to enter their location manually.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on your browser Policy, regarding to Mozilla for example :

> If you allow a website to get your location via this service, we will
>   collect, depending on the capabilities of your device, information
>   about the wifi routers closest to you, cell ids of the cell towers
>   closest to you, and the strength of your wifi or cell signal. We use
>   this information to return an estimated location to the Firefox
>   browser and the Firefox browser sends the estimated location to the
>   requesting website. For each request sent to our service, we also
>   collect IP address, user agent information, and unique identifier of
>   your client. We use this information to distinguish requests, not to
>   identify you.

[Google Location Service in Mozilla Firefox Privacy Policy](https://www.google.com/privacy/lsf.html)

Basic usage :

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
} else {
  /* geolocation IS NOT available */
}
```